# mypy not properly parsing a file of constants

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, static-typing

I have a Python project that uses a common file for constants, `consts.py`, that all of the code in the project uses and these same constants should be available to any process that instantiates the module.

When I run `stubgen python_project --include-private`, the stub files are created and look OK (like below):

```
# consts.pyi
from typing import List

ASSOCIATED: List[str]
DISASSOCIATED: List[str]
PAGE_NUMBER_FLOOD_PROTECTION: int
```

The `consts.py` file looks like this:

```
# consts.py
from typing import List

ASSOCIATED: List[str] = ['associated', 'associating']
DISASSOCIATED: List[str] = ['disassociated', 'disassociating']
PAGE_NUMBER_FLOOD_PROTECTION: int = 2000
```

The project structure looks like this:

```
python_project
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── aws_client.py
└── consts.py
```

The `__init__.py` includes the constants as enumerated imports and `MANIFEST.in` uses a `global-include *.pyi` directive. Here is the `__init__.py`:

```
# __init__.py
from .aws_client import AwsClient
from .consts import (
    ASSOCIATED,
    DISASSOCIATED,
    PAGE_NUMBER_FLOOD_PROTECTION,
)
```

However, when I attempt to use the constants, they are marked as 'Module has no attribute "consts"' by `mypy`. Here is an example of usage (which, of course, works in the scripts and modules, but is flagged by `mypy`:

```
import python_project as pp

x = 'some_string'
if x in pp.consts.ASSOCIATED:
    do_something()
```

I could override this behavior, but I would prefer to have it work as intended.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: "*The __init__.py includes the constants as enumerated imports*" You mean your `__init__.py` directly imports `ASSOCIATED`, `DISASSOCIATED`, etc. and re-exports them? Can you [edit] in your `__init__.py` as well? I'm guessing `pp.ASSOCIATED` should be the correct usage then.

Comment: @GinoMempin, the `__init__.py` is now in the question. And, to access the consts, `pp.consts.whatever` is OK during runtime, just not for `mypy`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: running `python -m mypy python_project` yields "Success: no issues found in 2 source files". This ignores the `aws_client.py` file, since I have no idea what's in there (and whether it could conflict with your constants module). This is for Python 3.9.9 and MyPy verison 0.931.

Comment: And when I test it on your "script" at the bottom of your question (replacing `do_something` with `pass`, like `python -m mypy testit`, I see "Success: no issues found in 1 source file". `testit.py` lives in the same directory the `python_project` subdirectory is located.

Comment: *Running* the script, however, fails; for the obvious reason that the three constants don't have any value set. The error message is "ImportError: cannot import name 'ASSOCIATED' from 'python_project.consts'". Then I give the three constants values (corresponding to their types), things seem to work fine.

Comment: @9769953, this issue is not that the scripts do not work (they work as expected), but that mypy continues to flag the consts file and its contents as `'Module has no attribute "consts"'`...

Comment: `consts` is a module in the `pp` package, but `python_package/__init__.py` never exports the name `consts`. Your constants are available as `pp.ASSOCIATED`, etc.